# i want change code python light time off in packet tracer after leave sensor 10 sc

Tags: python

```
from gpio import *
from time import *
from physical import *
from ioeclient import *
from environment import *


ENVIRONMENT_IMPACT_DIM = 10
VOLUME_AT_RATE = 100000

state = 0;  # 0 off, 1 low, 2 high
lastTimeInSeconds = 30

def main():
    setup()
    while True:
        loop()

        
def setup():

    IoEClient.setup({
        "type": "Light",
        "states": [
        {
            "name": "Status",
            "type": "options",
            "options": {
                "0": "Off",
                "1": "Dim",
                "2": "On"
            },
            "controllable": True
        }
        ]
    })

    IoEClient.onInputReceive(onInputReceiveDone)
    global state
    add_event_detect(0, detect)
    state = restoreProperty("state", 0)
    setState(state)

def detect():
    processData(customRead(0), False)
    
def onInputReceiveDone(analogInput):
    processData(analogInput, True)
        
def restoreProperty(propertyName, defaultValue):
    value = getDeviceProperty(getName(), propertyName)
    if  not (value is "" or value is None):
        if  type(defaultValue) is int :
            value = int(value)

        setDeviceProperty(getName(), propertyName, value)
        return value
    return defaultValue


def mouseEvent(pressed, x, y, firstPress):
    global state
    if firstPress:
        setState(state+1)

def loop():
    updateEnvironment()
    sleep(1)


def processData(data, bIsRemote):
    if  len(data) <= 0 :
        return
    setState(int(data))


def setState(newState):
    global state
    if newState >= 3 :
        newState = 0
    state = newState

    analogWrite(A1, state)
    customWrite(0, state)
    IoEClient.reportStates(state)
    setDeviceProperty(getName(), "state", state)

def updateEnvironment():
    global VOLUME_AT_RATE
    global ENVIRONMENT_IMPACT_DIM
    volumeRatio = float(VOLUME_AT_RATE) / Environment.getVolume()
    if  state is 0 :
        Environment.setContribution("Visible Light", 0,0, True)
    elif  state is 1:
        Environment.setContribution("Visible Light", ENVIRONMENT_IMPACT_DIM*volumeRatio, ENVIRONMENT_IMPACT_DIM*volumeRatio, False)
    elif  state is 2 :
        Environment.setContribution("Visible Light", ENVIRONMENT_IMPACT_DIM*2*volumeRatio, ENVIRONMENT_IMPACT_DIM*2*volumeRatio, False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You need to add some explanatory text to tell us what you expect this code to do, and what it's not doing correctly.  Your title is not nearly clear enough.

Comment: Please use `if state == 0:` when comparing numbers, not `if state is 0:`.  And I don't see anything here that sets the light time to 10 seconds.